# How to change the value of the class name in HTML document with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few divs with a single class name, my objective is to change the class name value of the div when a particular link is clicked, and below was my approach.

I stored class name values in an array, then used `document.getElementsByClassName("test")` and stored it into an array elements, and then I ran a for loop to replace class name value. :

```
function changeClass(value){
    style = [ 'view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view     view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth' ];
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for(var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        elements[i].className = style[value];
    }   
}
```

When I run this code, only a single div class name is replaced. I want all the class name to be replaced.

Comment: `i--` or `for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++)`

Comment: that was a grave error, thanks mate for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function changeClass(value){
    style = [ 'view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view     view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth' ];
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for(var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        elements[i].className = style[value];
    }   
}
```

**OR**

```
function changeClass(value){
    style = [ 'view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view     view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth' ];
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        elements[i].className = style[value];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
style = [ 'view view-first', 'view view-second', 'view     view-third', 'view view-fourth', 'view view-fifth' ];
$('.test').each(function(i,v) {
     if (style[i]) {
        $(this).attr('class',style[i]);
     }
});
```

Comment: you have the jquery tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems = $('.oldclasses');
elems.removeClass('oldclasses');
elems.addClass('newClass');
```

So you not need $.each function for that jquery can apply the commands to all elems or single elem.